# Version Control Solution that Can Handle Large Binary Files

Tags: version-control, version

I have a business application that uses datasets that are primarily text based but within the dataset there are also large binary files, upward of about 10 GB.  We need to identify a version control system that will support all of these files.  I really like the way Subversion works, and would like to use something to this tune but every time I setup a test environment it chokes when it hits a large file.

Before everyone responds and tells me "you shouldn't use a VC system for large binaries" - Yes I am aware of that!

I am looking for something that A. Allows you to commit files of any size into a repository, or B. A hybrid solution that could use version control to hold the regular files, and a filer that could hold all the large files.  Ideally I would be able to use a client like tortoise to checkout the entire dataset and then have all of the files come down from both of these sources into a working copy.

I am really banging my head against the wall with this and am hoping someone has some ideas as to what to do.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I think GIT can do that.
Why?

1. GIT is always locale
2. Never creates deltas from different file versions.
3. It saves any content under a for the content unique hash. Same data, same hash. Two time the same big binary will only be saved one time.
4. A GIT repository can have many remotes. A remote have not be a git server. Any reachable directory can be a target to push changes. So for example you could push your local repository changes to a clone of the repository sitting on a network share or a sftp server. This means you can use a large binary optimized transport mechanism ;)

Hope that helps. Just starting to evaluate GIT depending on the feature of many remotes for a repository. Because you can use it for staging a project to.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial with [Largefiles extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension)